# Web development Restful API Server doesn't set cookie in the browser but it works in Postman

Tags: reactjs, cookies, mern

[image: Picture of Postman. Cookie works.]

[image]

CODE URL: **https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xjrDxmYuBkfSa5zF_xuRa2Uqh_aiixwt_KbZPYy-dVM/edit?usp=sharing**

Reactjs: localhost:4000
Server.js: localhost:3000

Why doesn't my code store the cookie in the browser even though the login works(password verification)? I stored the cookie in server.js using res.cookie('token', token).send({ "token": token });

However, when I use Postman application and use localhost:3000/login, the cookie called "token" is shown in the header, it works.